# Best way to define makefile dependencies when the compiler doesn't generate them?

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I'm creating a makefile to build an existing project.  We're using GNU Make 4, but the compiler doesn't automatically generate dependency information so I'm trying to determine the best way to specify dependencies for code that includes header files which in turn may include header files.  Due to the complexity of the codebase, I think it will be unrealistic to traverse the entire #include tree, gather up all the header files, and then specify them for each source file.

One solution is to create makefile definitions of each header file and its direct dependencies, then create a recipe for a header file that touches that header file to trigger the recompile of the source that includes it:

```
a123.o: a123.c header1.h 

header1.h: header2.h

header2.h: header3.h

# Recipes
%.o:
    # compile command for building a .o

%.h:
    @touch $@
```

This seems to work; if `header3.h` changes, then the `%.h` recipe updates header2.h's timestamp, which causes header1.h's timestamp to be updated, which causes `a123.o` to be rebuilt.

However, it seems messy, with all the `touch`ing, plus it seems odd to create a recipe for a source file that isn't directly compiled.  Is this the correct way to do this sort of thing, or is there a cleaner approach?  Please note that I simplified my question; in reality several languages are in use with different file extensions, the compiler isn't GCC, and the output isn't a `.o` file.  But the logic is exactly the same.

Comment: Is the inclusion of header files the only kind of dependency you're interested in? You could probably write a script in, say, perl, to write the dependency files for you (without touching headers).

Comment: I suppose I could write something to walk the includes and generate a flattened list of header dependencies, but then if a header file is added or removed at some point, the developer who makes that change will need to do a lot of work to adjust the makefile definitions for everything that directly or indirectly includes that file.  Doing it the way I listed above means you only need to manage a source file's direct includes.  I'm just wondering if there's a similar but cleaner approach, though.

Comment: One way or the other you'll have to specify which files depends on which other files. Whether the compiler does it, or you do it by hand, or you write a script that does it (must not be such a challenge in Python). Basically what `gcc` does with this kind of option is creating a target for each files with the correct dependencies, so that's the behavior you'll want to reproduce. Then you include the dependency files in the Makefile.

Comment: Now you can parse only one file after the other, so when compiling a file, you parse it and create the dependency file, just like gcc. No need to parse all the project each time.

Comment: Are you suggesting I place code in the recipe for `%.o:` (in the makefile example above) that, after compiling, traverses all includes for the source file that was just compiled and then creates a dependency file with those items?  That's a really interesting solution.